# Is there a runtime difference between SELECT * and SELECT explicit columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have a theoretical table with millions of rows:

```
Person table
ID             int
first_name     varchar(50)
last_name      varchar(50)
date_inserted  datetime
middle_name    varchar(50)
nick_name      varchar(50)
favorite_color varchar(50)
birth_date     datetime
last_edited    datetime
```

And my query is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE last_edited > subdate(now(), 2)
```

which returns tens of thousands of rows.

Is there any significant runtime difference between that query and running

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    date_inserted, 
    middle_name, 
    nick_name, 
    favorite_color, 
    birth_date, 
    last_edited 
FROM Person
    WHERE last_edited > subdate(now(), 2);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  The run-time difference is going be based on the volume of data returned.  This is the same for the two queries, because the same columns are referenced.

Often, columns are listed explicitly so only the needed columns are included.  That can benefit performance, and well as making the code more robust with respect to changes in the table structure.

Comment: Just to add to that, it boils down to database engine's interpretation of our SQL statement and how it creates the `execute plan`.   In your example both queries should create the same `execute plan` and database engine should take the same exact steps to return data. Thus no runtime difference should be observed.

Comment: I'd also add that for readabilty purposes listing the columns makes your statements much easier to understand.  If you were to look at a "select * " type statement, you can't tell by looking at it what columns are going to be returned, so you end up executing the statement just to see the returned columns.  Most SQL editors have functions which will let you quickly select all the columns to populate your statement, so I would say that you should always explicitly list your columns.